# Google Sheet Script to Copy Data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am recording employee job times and these are entered in a Google sheet. At the end of each day I have schedules which copy every day's records from the "Real Time" sheet into the "History" sheet, copying whatever data has been collected. There are varying numbers of entries and 8 columns of data but I only want to copy 3 columns of data, which are a name, time and job number. At the moment I am using this code:

```
function dailyLogv2() {    
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Real Time');    
var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('History');    
var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();    
var range = sourceSheet.getRange('A1:C30');    
range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

The only problem is I can't figure out how to copy ONLY the entries there have been for that day.  The above code obviously copies 30 rows, so every day there are gaps in the History sheet if there are less than 30 entries. How do I create the code to ONLY copy the exact number of entries there have been? I think something like getValues() might work but I don't know how implement it.

Comment: Only take the dates whose value is greater than or equal to `new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()).valueOf()` &&  less than `new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()+1).valueOf()`  the last term may not be necessary if you don't have dates beyond the current date.

Comment: Do you want to get all the rows with data, or you want from those rows the ones from today? Could you share an example sheet?

Comment: Sorry should have explained better. The Real Time sheet is wiped clean every night with a time based trigger AFTER that day's data has been copied to the History sheet, so each day the entries in the Real Time sheet start in row 1. The History sheet contains ALL the previous data plus the info copied each day. I would share a sheet but I don't know how!

Comment: You can check [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and then share the sheet (or a copy of it without personal data) to `Anyone with the link`